# Определение оборудования подключенного к com-портам

Tags: windows

Существует ли готовое решение под Windows для определения оборудования подключенного к com-портам?Если нет то можно ли решить данную проблему с помощью "`mode comN /status`" ?

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь com не поддерживает устройства plug and play, поэтому нету.